# TLS certificate exchange may be malformed

Tags: tls, certificates

When I try to connect to xxx I get certificate errors.  One legacy Java application doesn't acknowledge the certificate at all, and FileZilla says it's being sent in the wrong order.  When they send me the certificate it looks correct, so I'm assuming the problem is with how it's being transmitted during the TLS handshake.  I'm can't find an application which will dump the entire stream, so I can't see what exactly is being sent.
Here's the FileZilla log.  Increasing the log level doesn't add any useful information

```
Status: Resolving address of rxdatadirector.catamaranrx.com
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error: Server sent unsorted certificate chain in violation of the TLS specifications
```

I'm tearing my hair out over this.  Can anyone see what the error is with the connection negotiation or am I nuts?

FYI product is IBM Sterling Commerce SFTP and FTPS component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you use Filezilla my guess is that you are using FTP. The following command connects to the FTP server, upgrades to TLS and shows you among other things the certificate chain:

```
openssl s_client -starttls ftp -connect rxdatadirector.catamaranrx.com:21
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/postalCode=55343/ST=Minnesota/L=Minnetonka/street=9900 Bren Road East/O=UnitedHealth Group Inc./OU=Enterprise SSL Pro/CN=rxdatadirector.catamaranrx.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/postalCode=55343/ST=Minnesota/L=Minnetonka/street=9900 Bren Road East/O=UnitedHealth Group Inc./OU=Enterprise SSL Pro/CN=rxdatadirector.catamaranrx.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 3 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 4 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

This means that this server first sends the server certificate [0], which is correct. Then it send the server certificate again [1], which is wrong. Then it send the intermediate certificate [2] which issued the server certificate , which is correct. Then it sends the next certificate in chain [3] which is also correct. But then it send the root CA [4] which should not be sent at all but will usually be simply ignored if sent.

Thus, you need to remove [1] and [4] and then it should be fine.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I should have used openssl.  Although I wouldn't have been able to interpret it correctly.  Thanks, I'll let the site owner know.